# Run unit tests every night with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, scheduling

I'm developing a project in Visual Studio 2012 with some other developers. In my project, every one is connected together with TFS 2012.

I'm writing a lot of unit-tests that testing the classes on my project.

**In a perfect world, I wish to:**

1. Run all my unit tests **every night**. It's will be nice if I could control the scheduling (e.g. on Sunday run X tests and on Monday run Y tests).
2. Getting report every day of which tests failed/passed. It would be nice to get an email sent to me.
3. Browse running history: view the running history of specific test.

**Is that possible?**

I've already viewed the solution "*Run tests after build*" and found it ineffective. It's bothersome that after each [build -> build solution] it's starts to run 100+ unit-tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use something like [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), this is Continuous integration Services, this will be build run test every time you check in,

Answer (score 0):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) is a continuous build machine, which it sounds like would meet your needs. You may have to intall some plugins, but it can do what you are talking abotu